# CSS Media Queries and My Nexus One (Or other Android phones)

Tags: android, css, node.js, media-queries, stylus

So I have 2 phones an Android Nexus One and a cheap simple Android device I bought for like $100 retail.

I am trying to make my website mobile device friendly using @media and CSS (I am actually using stylus and Node.JS so the code may look a bit funny).

So I added the following to my style

```
//trial 1
@media (max-width:480px)
  display none
//Trial 2
@media (resolution: 163dpi)
    display none
//Trial 3
@media (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio:0.75)
  display none
//Trial 4
@media screen and (max-width:480px)
  display none
```

At first I thought my screen was just super high res, but none of these help the less expensive device either. Everything seems to work fine in my browser so I am stumped.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding this `meta` tag to the `<head>` of your html:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: So just to clarify in case there are others using jade this would be meta(name="viewport", content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"). At which time the max-device-width 480px works THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Try from this list, hope it will help:

```
/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {

}
/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {

}
/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {

}
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {

}
/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {

}
/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {

}
/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {

}
/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {

}
/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As tw16 says, you need `width=device-width` to tell the browser not to pretend to have a bigger resolution. On another note, with recent versions of Stylus this is also legal:

```
.foo
  display block
  &
    @media (max-width:480px)
      display none
    @media (resolution: 163dpi)
      display none
    @media (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio:0.75)
      display none
    @media screen and (max-width:480px)
      display none
```

Which compiles to:

```
.foo {
  display: block;
}
@media (max-width:480px) {
  .foo {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media (resolution: 163dpi) {
  .foo {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio:0.75) {
  .foo {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
  .foo {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

I find this helps keeping the media queries related to the specification.